# Add window button to dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

Is it possible to add a Window Button ("Close", "Min", "Max") to a ModernUI Dialog?

```
ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Dialog", "How to add window Buttons?");
```

I could not find any information.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a dialog rather than just a window?

Comment: I like the theme of the ModernUI dialog, it is modal by default etc. If there was no easy way to add the "Close" button, then I'd use a window and style that.

Comment: I would suggest creating your own window control that inherits from Window, but give it custom behavior to act more like a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

A dialog is modal by default and by design. You shouldn't use min/max on them. The action buttons on the dialog will perform the close function.

That said, I recently implemented my own `DialogHelper` which you could adapt:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    None = 0,
    Error = 16,
    Stop = Error,
    Hand = Error,
    Question = 32,
    Warning = 48,
    Exclamation = Warning,
    Information = 64,
    Asterisk = Information
}

public static class DialogHelper
{
    public static bool? ShowMessage(string text, string title, MessageType messageType = MessageType.None)
    {
        var dlg = new ModernDialog();
        dlg.Buttons = new[] {dlg.OkButton};
        dlg.Title = title;
        dlg.Content = text;
        dlg.BackgroundContent = new DialogBackgroundContent(messageType);
        dlg.MinWidth = dlg.MinWidth + 200;

        bool? res = false;
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => res = dlg.ShowDialog()));
        return res;
    }
}
```

I did this mostly to abstract away the Modern UI framework, just in case I wanted to swap it out for something else later.

`DialogBackgroundContent` is just a XAML UserControl I'm using to decorate the background with a success/fail icon.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Cmc.Installer.Core.Controls.DialogBackgroundContent"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Path x:Name="SuccessIcon" Width="32" Height="32" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF00FF00" 
              Margin="0,32,32,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Data="M-150.204,626.126C-152.317,626.126 -154.429,626.126 -156.541,626.126 -167.642,633.42 -180.629,646.047 -189.668,657.238 -190.916,658.782 -192.945,662.362 -193.701,662.422 -194.041,662.448 -198.024,659.719 -198.614,659.297 -202.818,656.279 -205.779,653.709 -209.257,650.899 -211.248,652.172 -212.879,653.805 -214.153,655.797 -206.627,665.074 -200.283,675.534 -193.124,685.18 -181.491,665.11 -168.473,644.683 -152.796,629.006 -151.735,627.946 -149.817,626.933 -150.204,626.126z"/>

        <Path x:Name="FailureIcon" Visibility="Hidden" Width="32" Height="32" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFF0000" 
              Margin="0,32,32,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Data="M50,5C25.147,5,5,25.147,5,50c0,24.853,20.147,45,45,45s45-20.147,45-45C95,25.147,74.853,5,50,5z M55,75H45V65h10V75z   M55,60H45V25h10V60z"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


public partial class DialogBackgroundContent : UserControl
    {
        public DialogBackgroundContent(MessageType messageType = MessageType.None)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            switch (messageType)
            {
                case MessageType.None:
                    FailureIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    SuccessIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case MessageType.Error:
                    FailureIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    SuccessIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case MessageType.Question:
                    break;
                case MessageType.Warning:
                    break;
                case MessageType.Information:
                    FailureIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    SuccessIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("messageType");
            }
        }
    }
```

You might want to try swapping out `ModernDialog` for `ModernWindow` in my function for more flexibility.

`ModernWindow` is defined here: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/blob/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/Shared/Windows/Controls/ModernWindow.cs